# Creating an array of irregular numbers in Numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

In Octave if I want to create an array containing an irregular, non-linear set of numbers (e.g. 12, then from 20 to 95 in steps of 5, then 100 to 190 in steps of 10, then 200 to 500 in steps of 25) I can just do:

```
octave:1> nxtals = [12, 20:5:95, 100:10:190, 200:25:500]
nxtals =
Columns 1 through 13:
12    20    25    30    35    40    45    50    55    60    65    70    75
Columns 14 through 26:
80    85    90    95   100   110   120   130   140   150   160   170   180
Columns 27 through 39:
190   200   225   250   275   300   325   350   375   400   425   450   475
Column 40:
500
```

Is there an elegant, Pythonic (perhaps NumPythonic) equivalent in Numpy/Python3? If I do a list of ranges in Python I get an error:

```
>>> q=[12, list(range(20, 50, 5)), list(range(50, 100, 10)),list(range(200,501,25))]
>>> numpy.array(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    numpy.array(q)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I suspect I need to use something like `numpy.ravel()` but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy defines an object called [`r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) that can do this.   It uses the `__getitem__` method to allow the use of the slice notation `start:stop:step` to assemble sequences, so instead of calling it, you use square brackets.  For example:

```
In [1]: nxtals = np.r_[12, 20:100:5, 100:200:10, 200:525:25]

In [2]: nxtals
Out[2]: 
array([ 12,  20,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  50,  55,  60,  65,  70,  75,
        80,  85,  90,  95, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180,
       190, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to stack those input lists horizontally into a single 1D array -

```
import numpy as np
q = np.hstack( [[12], list(range(20, 50, 5)), list(range(50, 100, 10)),
                                            list(range(200,501,25)) ] )
```

Sample run -

```
In [295]: q = np.hstack( [[12], list(range(20, 50, 5)), list(range(50, 100, 10)),
     ...:                                                 list(range(200,501,25)) ] )

In [296]: q
Out[296]: 
array([ 12,  20,  25,  30,  35,  40,  45,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 200,
       225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500])
```